# Returning Invalid date in IOS for angularjs project when date is from different timezone

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, iphone, date

I'm working on an ionic angularJS project.

The date is returning from the database is like "2016-10-12T00:00:00.000+0200" (UTC+2 timezone)

I'm setting this to date field (Input type date) by changing the value as follows.

```
 $scope.datevalue = new Date($scope.datevalue);
```

The above statement is working in android and returning Indian timezone as "Wed Oct 12, 2016, 03:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" But not working in IOS and returning "Invalid Date"

Could you please give me a solution for this?

Comment: you can use Moment js **https://momentjs.com/**  for date issue in iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js) for resolving this. First import moment.js in your js library then write following code.

```
            if($scope.datevalue !== null){
                $scope.datevalue =  new Date(moment($scope.datevalue));
            }
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a custom date formatter for iOS.  In Swift:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "y-M-d'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-10-12T00:00:00.000+0200")
print(date) //Prints in UTC: Optional(2016-10-11 22:00:00 +0000)
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what is "from" in this ?         let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-10-12T00:00:00.000+0200")